# Enabling Contents Transfer on Sony a7iii/a7riii/a9

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

It seems like the remote API on the newer Sony models support the capabilities to transfer images, namely the device returns that it supports the `listContent` method when calling `getMethodTypes`. However the camera doesn't support `setCameraFunction` and when trying to start the transfer process by calling `listSchemes` it returns an "Unavailable" error.

It seems like Sony doesn't document the API for the new cameras, even though they are clearly supported! Does anyone have any insight on how I can gain access to these functions (i.e. make them available)?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was correct that this is unsupported on newer Sony Cameras. This now requires the use of the "Send to Smartphone" functionality which uses pretty standard [UPnP transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play)